# I want to replace "take place" with occur and happen

Tags: synonyms

I want to replace the first verb with verbs "occured" or "happened" in order not to double the verb "take place" in this sentence but I dont know if the above-mentioned words collocate with the word "execution"

"The execution took place/occured/happened on the so-called castle [...] It took place in October 1942."

Answer (score 4):

First off, I see no point in writing two sentences instead of one sentence as follows:

The execution was carried out/took place in the so-called castle in October 1942. If the execution was unexpected or without being planned, you can use occured/happened instead of took place.

However. If you still want to keep two sentences, you can rephrase your sentences as follows:

The execution was carried out in the so-called castle. It took place in October 1942.

Answer (score 1):

There are online tools for this, e.g. [For Better English](http://forbetterenglish.com).

> "execution took place" results in 0.077 hits / million.
>
> "execution occurred" (note the extra r) results in 0.016 hits /
>   million.
>
> "execution happened" results in 0.003 hits / million.

So 'occurred' is used less often, but still quite a good choice.

Comment: This site sucks. I type the most common phrases and it does not find them.